# Import aws resources into terraform module that has a for_each

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to import a couple of  cloudfront distributions into terraform. As they are very similar (and can be managed together, I wanted to create 1 resource with a `for_each` and then import them into this resource).

The module looks like this:

```
variable "cloudfront_configurations" {
  default = {
    distro_1 = {
      aliases = ["url_of_distro1.com"],
    },
    distro_2 = {
      aliases = ["url_of_distro2.com"],
    },
  }
}


module "cloudfront_distribution" {
  for_each = var.cloudfront_configurations
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"
  version = "2.7.0"

  aliases = each.value.aliases
  ...
}
```

These cloudfront distro's already exist in AWS, and I wanted to import them into terraform using:

```
terraform import module.cloudfront_distribution[\"distro_1\"].aws_cloudfront_distribution[0] IDOFDISTRO1
```

This keeps giving me the error `no matches found: module.cloudfront_distribution["distro_1"].aws_cloudfront_distribution[0]`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research it appeared to be a quotation error. When referencing a module from cli, you need to quote the entire name like so:

```
terraform import 'module.cloudfront_distribution["distro_1"].aws_cloudfront_distribution[0]' IDOFDISTRO1
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html#example-import-into-resource-configured-with-for_each

Answer (score 3):

When you try to import something in Terraform, usually the easiest way to get its ID is to just do a `terraform plan` and check the output

In your case, you're trying to import

```
  module                         // check the module
  .cloudfront_distribution       // named cloudfront_distribution
  [\"distro_1\"]                 // with ID distro_1 in its for_each
  .aws_cloudfront_distribution   // inside, it will have a aws_cloudfront_distribution
  [0]                            // ?
```

If you check [the Terraform docs about referencing values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html), you'll see that the structure is `<RESOURCE TYPE>.<NAME>`. In your ID, you're missing the name and putting just a `[0]` as if it was the first resource created by a `count`

If you don't want to use the `terraform plan` trick I mentioned before, you'll have to check [the docs of the module you're using](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws/latest?tab=resources). In there, you'll see that the resource you're interested is `aws_cloudfront_distribution.this`

So the ID of your resource is `module.cloudfront_distribution["distro_1"].aws_cloudfront_distribution.this` (notice that I changed `[0]` by `.this`)

Comment: The distribution ID is just a fake in here(I didn't want to use the real one)

The terraform module for cloudfront is created by a `count` (https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudfront/blob/master/main.tf), so I guess the [0] should be okay.

For the sake of argument I tried importing with these, but it gives the same error:
module.cloudfront_distribution[\"distro_1\"].aws_cloudfront_distribution.this[0]
module.cloudfront_distribution[\"distro_1\"].aws_cloudfront_distribution.this
module.cloudfront_distribution[\"distro_1\"]

Comment: Then I recommend you running `terraform plan` and note down the ID Terraform assigns to the distribution. That's the one you'll need to use

Comment: That's the weirdest part still... When I run the plan command, I get this as a resource name: `module.cloudfront_distribution["account"].aws_cloudfront_distribution.this[0]` (account is the real value I use as key in my variable). And when I copy this resource name, still same error. I'm at a loss now.... Even tried different version of the terraform command